# Why does cin.fail() behaves differently with decimal input and character input here?

Tags: c++

Both Characters and decimal numbers have distinct data types defined in c++.Why  am I getting following output ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int a;
cin >> a;
cout << (cin.fail());     //Output is 1 when input is a character
return 0;                 //Output is 0 when input is a decimal number
}
```

Comment: Because reading a number fails when you don't type in a number, but doesn't fail when you type in a number?

Answer (score 0):

Characters and numbers do indeed have distinct data types, but your code is explicitly looking for an *int* in the above because the statement `cin >> a;` has an `int` as the rhs of the `operator>>`. This will fail if you try to input a non-numeric string.

Answer (score 0):

`cin.fail()` will return `false`, when last operation was successful and `true` otherwise. When you pass `true` and `false` to `cout`, it prints `1` and `0` respectively.

If you want to read a number and user sends you a character and you read it, this operation is considered as a fail. If you were reading a character and user passed character, `cin.fail()` would return `true`, but you were reading a number, so it returned `false`.